# How to run a sbt program in one line with arguments?

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I run my project with a single command of sbt? I tried

```
sbt run src/main/resources/mydata.txt
```

after adding

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample")
mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample")
```

to the build.sbt, but I get

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at com.mywebsite.MyExample$.main(MyExample.scala:17)
        at com.mywebsite.MyExample.main(MyExample.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Clearly the argument did not find its way to my call of `args(0)` in the main method. So what did I do wrong, how do I do it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sbt "run src/main/resources/mydata.txt"